# How to redirect all pages in the subdomain except a few?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a subdomain where I need to redirect all pages to the main domain except a few pages.

For example, `http://subdomain.domain.com/contact-us` and `http://subdomain.domain.com/thank-you` pages should not redirect. All other pages should be redirected to `http://www.domain.com`.

The main domain is hosted elsewhere and the subdomain is pointed to the server I have access to. In the subdomain's .htaccess, can I have something like this:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?!(contact-us|thank-you)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:contact-us|thank-you))(.*)/?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The negative lookahead `(?!(?:contact-us|thank-you))` ensures that what follows is neither `contact-us` nor `thank-you`.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)